# Is this Python login practically insecure?

Tags: python, security, authentication, brute-force

I was making a bot to sign on the the site of an open-source project's website(not going to mention any names), and I noticed that my bot was not hitting a max login attempts ban no matter how many times I attempted to login with incorrect credentials.

```py
def login(account,passwd):
    r = requests.post("http://nottheprojectname.com/~~app/action.php",
                    data={'act': "login",
                          'name': account,
                          'pass': passwd,
                          'keyid': ""
                    })

return r.text
```

I was using a Python script like the one shown above to login, and I decided to make a test script demonstrate how an account could be brute-forced.

```py
import re
import requests    

def dictionary_crack(account):
    attempts = 0
    with open('giant_PW_list.txt', 'r') as f:
        for passwd in f:
            resp = login(account, passwd)
            if re.findall("loggedin\"\:[a-z]+",resp) == [u'loggedin":true']:
                return account + ": " + passwd
            else:
                attempts += 1
                print trys
        else:
            input("All login attemts on "+account+" failed")
```

I showed this script to the admins of the project, and they dismissed it saying it wouldn't work because the login attempts would be to slow to preform. However, I tried this on a test account I made and was able to preform around **10,000 login attempts a minute** with one of these scripts running. Not extremely fast for a brute-force attack, but it certainly doesn't seem negligible(especially if multiple attacks were preformed simultaneously on the same account at once with sequential dictionaries).

**This all seems ridiculous and easily fixable to me. I am not experienced in web-security, so I feel conflicted correcting people who are much more knowledgeable in the field of web-security than I am.**

Comment: The proper way to make this sort of brute-force approach "too slow" would be to limit login attempts to something like one per second. If the site's administrators didn't listen, I'd suggest talking to the site's users, because it's their accounts that will get compromised if (when) the site gets hacked.

Comment: to slow -> too slow preform -> perform And it's more a dictionary than a brute-force attack...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks. I don't need to rebuild the system myself(although since it is open-source I could help fix it) I wanted to be able to show the site admins an outside reference so they would listen to me.

Comment: @DavidGreydanus: if I correct only the small typos, I cannot (edit must be 6 characters at least). And since I am not 100% sure that using brute-force is incorrect, my lazy side won't fix this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server should track bad login attempts by username and by password. You need to store this in app/global state, not session.

Don't even bother tracking IP addy, blackhat will just use an anonymyzing proxy.

Upon U bad username login attempts or P bad password attempts the server should demand a correct CAPTCHA value or Proof of Work†.

If user authenticates, return an HMAC'd ["trusted user agent"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Slow_Down_Online_Guessing_Attacks_with_Device_Cookies) cookie, so the user can skip CAPTCHA or Proof of Work in the future.

Don't lock out people's accounts, as you're just letting a hacker DoS them. Don't sleep() on the server, as you're keeping connections open longer than necessary, possibly DoSing yourself.

You can do a lot of this with modsecurity.

Here's the OWASP guide: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks

†  Have the web browser calculate the prime factors of a real big number

Comment: Thanks. I really wanted to be able to show the site admins this post to give my position some legitimacy.

Answer (score 0):

The site administrators are correct in that when users have good random passwords, an online brute force is not reasonable.  Lets take for example all possible passwords that are 7 characters in length.  Lets assume each passwords is Alpha Numeric [a-zA-Z], 0-9, or special character !@#$%^&*()_+-=  That gives us 26 (lower) + 26 (upper) + 14 (special character) = 66 possibilities for each character.  For 7 character passwords 66^7 roughly equal to 5.4*10^12 or 5 trillion passwords.  To test each of these passwords individually at 1000 passwords per minute would take about 10,378 years.

This scenario does make a bad assumption in that users have good random passwords.  This has been proven time and time again to be untrue and it is likely a users password can be guessed using readily available password lists.  This is when the techniques of blocking brute forcing are useful as another poster recommended.